# Implement card flip animation between two Views using AnimatorSet

Tags: android, animation

I am making a kanji flashcards app. I want to have a `LinearLayout` representing the front and another representing the back of the card, both i have declared in one XML layout.
Problem is, the second `LinearLayout` is always invisible, the first one animates normally.
Is there anyway to make a method call while the animation is ongoing? I want to set the visibility of the first layout to `GONE` and the second to `VISIBLE`?

Or is there another better way to implement the flip card?

Below is my code. Thank in advance.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_container_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ff825e4e" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/card_front_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/card_shape_front">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="傘"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textSize="200sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/card_back_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/card_shape_front">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="QWERTY"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

FlashcardsFragment.java

```
public class FlashcardsFragment extends Fragment
{
    private AnimatorSet showFrontAnim = new AnimatorSet();
    private AnimatorSet showBackAnim = new AnimatorSet();
    private boolean isShowingBack = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flashcard, container, false);

        LinearLayout cardFront = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.card_front_layout);
        LinearLayout cardBack = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.card_back_layout);

        // Load the animator sets from XML and group them together

        AnimatorSet leftIn   = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater
                .loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.card_flip_left_in);
        AnimatorSet rightOut = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater
                .loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.card_flip_right_out);
        AnimatorSet leftOut  = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater
                .loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
        AnimatorSet rightIn  = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater
                .loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.card_flip_right_in);

        leftIn.setTarget(cardFront);
        rightOut.setTarget(cardBack);
        showFrontAnim.playTogether(leftIn, rightOut);

        leftOut.setTarget(cardFront);
        rightIn.setTarget(cardBack);
        showBackAnim.playTogether(leftOut, rightIn);

        LinearLayout cardContainer = (LinearLayout) 
                v.findViewById(R.id.card_container_layout);
        // Set the flip animation to be triggered on container clicking
        cardContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (isShowingBack) {
                    showFrontAnim.start();
                    isShowingBack = false;
                }
                else {
                    showBackAnim.start();
                    isShowingBack = true;
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** : My problem has been solved, i changed the container layout to `FrameLayout`, this way the two views can overlap each other. Thank you for all :))

Answer (score 1):

In your AnimatorSet you could add an extra animation for setting the alpha to 0 or 1. Only use the startdelay method to set your 1 ms long animation in the middle of the total AnimationSet length.

If you want to improve your flip further look into the AdapterViewFlipper :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
cardFront.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
cardBack.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This will change the visibility of your layouts inside the code at any place you want.

Comment: Thank, but what i want to know is how to insert those calls while the Views are animating.

Comment: That won't work because the animation haven't started yet. i want to change View at half animation time.

Comment: @kradragon I see. Well, I guess isn't the best solution but since you know the animations duration, you could set a handler to, after the durations half amount of time, the view change it's visibility. Are you aware of how to use a handler? I could put some piece of could in my answer if you want.
EDIT: I guess Adam solution would work. Take a look at it.